# Node.js for data-driven websites

Tags: node.js, e-commerce, express

Can anyone use node.js (express.js or whatever) for a data-driven website like e-commerce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Node.js is a server technology which can be used for developing *any kind* of website including data-driven and e-commerce.